# Place domain in Tweet without Twitter encoding it?

Tags: twitter

We have a custom twitter handle for posting some event info to a social wall application. One of the Tweets is something like `1pm example.com voting begins` We want it to show just like that on our wall, however Twitter makes the `example.com` a link and creates a shortened url for it. So our app shows something like `1pm http://484j/348.com voting begins`

Is there any way to tell Twitter not to shorten `example.com` and just leave it as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experimented with this, and there are a couple of ways.

- example.com <- Will Link
- /example.com <- No link when started with a slash
- example．com <- No link using full-width stop
- example｡com <- No link with Halfwidth ideographic full stop
- example․com <- No link with [One Dot Leader](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/8228)

See https://twitter.com/edent/status/558013466494369792 for proof.

So, basically, you have to use a unicode character which *looks* like a period, but *isn't*.

Of course, if a user copies & pastes the text into a browser, it won't work.